# interpretation of coefficient in pre/post study

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-encoding

Let's say the government wants to implement a policy that will reduce the difference between what a person pays for a house and the original ask price. If a house sells for 100k and the original ask was 110 the percent difference 10/110 was 9%. that percent is the dependent variable.

The government implements the program on May 15th and they implement it by having different real estate companies change their policies. They put companies into a control group where nothing changes and 2 test groups - test group 1 and test group 2.

There are 3 companies in the control group with 100 houses sold pre May 15th and 75 sold after for a total of 175 total observations in the control group.

There are 4 companies in the test group 1 with 85 houses sold pre May 15th and 40 sold after for a total of 125 total observations in test group 1.

There are 6 companies in the test group 1 with 70 houses sold pre May 15th and 100 sold after for a total of 170 total observations in test group 2.

To see if the policy resulted in a change in the outcome variable percent a regression is run

```
PERCENT ~ PRE_POST + GROUP + PRE_POST*GROUP + INTEREST RATE
```

where

- Percent is the percent mentioned above - the difference of asking price and
  sale price
- PRE_POST is an indicator variable that is 1 for
  observations post may 15th and 0 otherwise
- GROUP is an indicator
  variable indicating the control group (reference group), or test
  group 1 or test group 2
- INTeRST RATE is the interest rate of a 30-yr
  mrotgage at the time the house sold

The outcome of the regression is below

```
Intercept   -.40    significant at 1%   level
PRE_POST:POST   .15 significant at 5% level      
GROUP1  -.05                 
GROUP2  .17                  
INTEREST_RATE   -0.5    significant at 1%   level        
POST:GROUP1 -.32             
POST:GROUP2 -.50    -2  significant at 1%   level
```

HOw does one interpret these interaction coefficient?

I was thinking it means being in the post period and group 2 resulted a significantly lower percentage, -.50, compared to the control group. The interaction terms are relative to the control group?

What does it mean that POST:GROUP2 is highly negative and significant BUT GROUP2 is positive?

Also - Is the total impact of being in the post period and group 2 POST + GROUP2 + POST*GROUP2 = .15 + .17-.50 = -.18?  But you can't say anything about that .18. You can only say something about the individual numbers .15, .17 and -.50 so how does one interpret these coefficients?